# Can't boot on Windows 8, with triple boot

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-8

For the second time, ubuntu replace, again, my windows 8. Ubuntu replace the boot of windows 8 with his evil grub, so i can't boot in windows 8. When i try to boot in windows 8, he reload grub. :@
So i have a triple boot, with Mac Osx, Ubuntu 14.04, and Windows 8. I can't boot in ubuntu since upgrade of ubuntu (13 to 14).

So i can't use my windows. Thanks ubuntu again. :@
I have already use boot repair, reinstall grub. I use refit to boot in Mac or Ubuntu or Windows 8, but since the update, refit show me: Mac osx, Ubuntu, and Ubuntu again. And when i choose Windows in grub, he reload grub.

There is a past of boot repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7943200/

Thanks for your help, and sorry for my bad english, i'm french. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing BURG? if I'm not mistaken it works better in this kind of situations.

Comment: I think BURG didn't resolve my problem, it's just a grub with a graphic theme. rEfit do the same work :/